# What makes up and down quarks so special?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

One of the ways a lot of different mesons and baryons are grouped is by their up and down quark content. There's also isospin, which is admittedly a subset of a more general symmetry. But the Wikipedia [shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mesons#Pseudoscalar_mesons) [it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_baryons#JP_=_1/2+_baryons) while having a separate quantum number for each of the other quark flavors. Why was this worth including on the Wikipedia page? Why didn't they just have separate up and down quantum numbers?

Comment: I think what you're asking is why each [flavour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flavour_(particle_physics)#Quarks) defines a quark species, but other quantum numbers are not treated similarly. It may be worth making this clearer in an edit (if I'm right).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a unique feature about $u$ and $d$ quarks. Their masses are indeed very different in comparative terms—one is twice as heavy as the other;  but this is *irrelevant* in the scale of hadrons, even pseudoscalars (which are light freaks, by dint of their Nambu-Goldstone property): their mass difference is negligible in comparison to $\Lambda_{QCD}>200$ MeV, the gorilla in the room, which sets the mass scale for hadrons. As a result, isospin is a "good" symmetry, making them equivalent, in one sense, when one ignores electromagnetism and focusses on the strong-binding states.

> Why was this worth including on the Wikipedia page? Why didn't they just have separate up and down quantum numbers?

The reason to focus on the more abstract isospin  symmetry is because it is "easier"/more-powerful in understanding mass splittings, coupling ratios, etc, within isomultiplets, than nigh-impossible combinatorics of quark replacements. (You may get a glimpse of this complexity if you inspect the *full* constituent wavefunction of the neutron, for example.) In practical terms, constituent quarks are a drag, which is why they were adopted so late after their inception/proposal.

It is actually fortunate the strange quark is noticeably higher in mass, but ***still*** lower than $\Lambda_{QCD}$, which makes it noticeable, but still describable in terms of an explicitly broken meaningful symmetry, flavor $SU(3)$, which, historically, led to the elucidation of flavor and the introduction of quarks.

Few consider the charm-quark classification of flavor $SU(4)$ terribly useful, except as a means to account for states. The third generation quarks need no cover; they stick out like sore thumbs, especially the odd-man-out top.

Answer (score 1):

@Cosmas Zachos is entirely correct. One addition is that it is not isospin $I$ that determines quark content, it is the eigenstate on the 3rd axis with quantum number $I_3$ that signifies quark content via:

$$I_3 = \frac 1 2 (n_u - n_d) $$

So the pions constitute and iso-triplet ($I=1$) state. Hence, with the isospin quantum number as $|I,I_3\rangle$, we have:

$$|1,1\rangle =\pi^+ = u\bar d$$
$$|1,0\rangle =\pi^0 = \frac{u\bar u-d\bar d}{\sqrt 2}$$
$$|1,-1\rangle =\pi^- = d\bar u$$

where the quark content is shown on the right. For those only familiar with the quantum addition of 2 electron spin, it is clear from the mathematics why the name "isospin" fits.

Note that the quarks in the $\pi^0$ are not in flavor eigenstates (which are the $I_3=\pm \frac 1 2$ eigenstates), and hence the state is properly described by total isospin quantum numbers.

In analogy to the spin singlet combination of two spinors, there is a $|0,0\rangle$ combination with identical quark content to the $\pi^0$:

$$|0,0\rangle =\omega = \frac{u\bar u+d\bar d}{\sqrt 2}$$

That is, however, a vector meson, and the pseudo scalar partner to the $\pi^0$ is really the SU(3)-flavor pseudoscalar:

$$|0,0\rangle =\eta' = \frac{u\bar u+d\bar d+s\bar s}{\sqrt 3}$$

So for isospin (aka SU(2)-flavor symmetry), there is just more information in $I,I_3$ than just quark content.

Comment: Can you point me to some good tutorials that explain what all this math means?